# Using ranges across multiple worksheets for in-cell dropdown for data validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have multiple worksheets where each has a column representing a "unique key".  On the final sheet, I want to use data validation to create an in-cell dropdown list that is a union of the key ranges from the other sheets.

The formula builder generates this when I make my multi-sheet selection:

```
='Windows Servers:Web Services'!$A$2:$A$5
```

Excel throws exception:

```
This type of reference cannot be used in a Data Validation formula.
```

So I create a named range referencing the same range above.  It works and I am even able to use it in formulas.  However, when I attempt to use it as the source for data validation, I get this:

```
The Source currently evaluates to an error.
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in Excel 2010?